# MUI Link not working with over-mouse and on-click, only with one or other (React application)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

if anyone could please help, I am newer to Material UI and am using the Mui Button but as a Router Link by passing the component prop. I have 4 links in my nav bar that are mapped over from an array and displayed with onClick to navigate to their prospective page, one of the Links has a sub-array I wanted to add a mouseover to open. The problem is if with the mouseover the onclick link for just that tab isn't working but the mouseover is to open the menu. If I take off the mouse over the onclick works.
Any insight would be so appreciated! And please let me know if any other code is needed for insight!

```
onst Nav = () => {
 
  const [openServices, setOpenServices] = useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    if(event !== event.currentTarget){
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    }
  };


  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };


 {navButtons.map(({ name, link }) => {
            const isServices = name === 'Services';
            return (
              <Button
                to={link}
                component={RouterLink}
                id='basic-button'
                open={open}
                aria-controls={open ? "basic-menu" : undefined}
                aria-haspopup='true'
                aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
                onClick={handleClick}
                onMouseOver={isServices ? handleClick : undefined}
                fullWidth={false}
                sx={{
                  fontSize: isScrolling ? "17px" : "20px",
                  fontWeight: "900",
                  color: isScrolling ? "#244ba6" : "white",
                  textShadow: isScrolling ? "none" : "0px 1px 2px black",
                }}
              >
                {name}
                {name === "Services" ? (
                  <KeyboardArrowDownIcon className='shadow' />
                ) : null || (name === "Services" && isScrolling) ? (
                  <KeyboardArrowDownIcon size='small' className='noShadow' />
                ) : null}
              </Button>)
          })}


<Menu
            id='basic-menu'
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={anchorEl?.innerText === 'SERVICES'  ? open : null}
            onClose={handleClose}
            MenuListProps={{
              "aria-labelledby": "basic-button",
              sx: { py: 0 },
            }}
          >
```

update! I found a work around that the mouse over and onclick will work but now the submenu is opening on every tab onclick... any ideas?

```
 {navButtons.map(({ name, link }) => {
            const isServices = name === 'Services';
            return (
              <Button
                to={link}
                component={RouterLink}
                id='basic-button'
                open={open}
                aria-controls={open ? "basic-menu" : undefined}
                aria-haspopup='true'
                aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
                onClick={handleClick}
                // onMouseOver={isServices ? handleClick : undefined}
                fullWidth={false}
                sx={{
                  fontSize: isScrolling ? "17px" : "20px",
                  fontWeight: "900",
                  color: isScrolling ? "#244ba6" : "white",
                  textShadow: isScrolling ? "none" : "0px 1px 2px black",
                }}
              >
                {name}
                {name === "Services" ? (
                  <KeyboardArrowDownIcon className='shadow' onMouseOver={handleClick}/>
                ) : null || (name === "Services" && isScrolling) ? (
                  <KeyboardArrowDownIcon size='small' className='noShadow' onMouseOver={handleClick}/>
                ) : null}
              </Button>)
          })}


          <Menu
            id='basic-menu'
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={open}
            // open={anchorEl?.innerText === 'SERVICES'  ? open : null}
            onClose={handleClose}
            onMouseLeave={handleClose}
            MenuListProps={{
              "aria-labelledby": "basic-button",
              sx: { py: 0 },
              // onMouseLeave: handleClose
            }}
          >
```